# How to cancel a redirect_to and replace with render in a controller?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-7, doorkeeper

I have a controller action that redirects, and I want to replace the response with render.

Yes, I know. "return early".

That will not work for this use case.

I want to change the response from `DoorKeeper`. This controller inherits from `DoorKeeper` and the `DoorKeeper` controller calls `redirect_to`.

My controller looks like this:

```
def new
  super

  render inline: ...
end
```

So, I am looking for a way to cancel the call to `redirect_to` in `super`.

I tried `response = ActionDispatch::Response.new`, but surprisingly that did not help.

Comment: not possible I'm afraid, you'll have to delete the call to super and invoke whatever `DoorKeeper#new` does (except redirect) locally. You can probably aggregate that 'stuff' into a helper that is called in both `DoorKeeper` and the descendant #new action.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Contrary to popular opinion, this is quite easy to do.

```
def redirect_to
end
```